# Use batch mode for dynamic listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using a dynamic message listener. An example is shown below. I want to convert this to a batch listener (consume multiple messages at once).

```
public class RetryMessageListener
    implements AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgement acknowledgement, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {

    }

}
```

Is there a way to convert this, so that the listener consumes a list of consumer records?
I am using spring-kafka with spring-boot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `BatchAcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener` instead.

```java
/**
 * Listener for handling a batch of incoming Kafka messages, propagating an acknowledgment
 * handle that recipients can invoke when the message has been processed. The list is
 * created from the consumer records object returned by a poll. Access to the
 * {@link Consumer} is provided.
 *
```